# Specify admins to which send email using App Engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, email, google-cloud-endpoints

I'm using App Engine to send emails to app admins. Events come from Google Cloud Endpoint and are executed using Pull Queues. Sometimes there's a need to inform admins about important changes which occurred in the app. Currently my code looks like this:

```
Message msg = new MimeMessage(session);
msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress("example@example.com", "Example"));
msg.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress("admins"));
msg.setSubject("Subject");
msg.setText(body);
Transport.send(msg);
```

This works fine and counts towards the `Admins Emailed` quota. The problem is,  emails are sent to all admins, but sometimes I need to specify which admins should receive the message. I know I can put their email addressed as `TO` recipients but it will probably count towards the `Recipients Emailed` quota which is quite small compared to the admin quota (100 emails vs 3,492,979)

Is there a way to send email only to selected admins which will count towards the `Admins Emailed` quota?

Comment: Have you tried testing it? 'admins' is a convenience method to include all admins, but individual addresses are actually checked if they are a registered admin of the application.

Comment: @Adam Yes I have. I've tested it once again using my email and it's counted towards the other quota, after sending one email I see in the console `Recipients Emailed 1 of 100`. I'm sure my email is in `admins` because I receive emails send to admins without any problem.

Comment: Hey! Have you by any chance found a solution to this?

Comment: @Sipka no, I think there's no solution for this

Comment: Thats too bad... By the way, I found out that you should send admin emails with sendToAdmins method instead of specitying "admins" as target address. If that is still relevant for you after 4 years lol.
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/mail/MailService